# MYSQL auto set expiry date

Tags: php, mysql, date, timestamp

i'm in new project and i need to set an expiry date to every post,
so that i could make an mysql event do delete all the posts that reached the expiry date.
i tried this:

```
alter table anuncios
MODIFY dataexpiracao TIMESTAMP on update TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,30,'NOW()');
```

that gives me an error f syntax... pls help me
i don't know if it is the best sollution but that's the unique i could found out after some research, if you know some other pls tell me and can you tell how to make the mysql event too?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in your table definition. However, you can create a trigger that automatically sets the date for you before inserting or updating the row.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

Here's an example that sets the expiration date 30 days from for all new rows.

```
    CREATE TRIGGER set_expiration_date 
    BEFORE INSERT ON `anuncios`
    FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.dataexpiracao  = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY);
```